# Hudson: Error after creating doxygen files; downgrade not working either

Tags: hudson, jenkins, doxygen

I'm having the following problem with Hudson after upgrading to 2.1.0:

After successfully creating  the doxygen output, the following exception occurs:

```
Publishing Doxygen HTML results.
The determined Doxygen directory is 'C:/doxy/myDir'.
FATAL: error
hudson.util.IOException2: java.io.IOException: Unconnected pipe
```

The error did not occur with 2.0.1, unfortunately, downgrading does not work - Hudson tells me, that it can't read the job files anymore.

Does anyone know the best way to deal with this? Is there a simple solution to either make the doxygen plugin work in 2.1.0 or to successfully downgrade to 2.0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly the problem was, but migrating to the newest Jenkins release and using the HTML report publisher plugin instead of the Doxygen plugin is at least a work